# Problem with non-autonomous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I've been trying to do exercise 1.8.5 of Arrowsmith Introduction to dynamical systems. I'm asked to show that
$ \varphi_1(t)=(2, exp(t))$ and $\varphi_2(t)=(exp(t), 1)$ are a  basis for the solution of $\dot{x}=A(t)x$ where
$$A(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
  2 & -2exp(-t) \\
  exp(t) & -1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The first solution of course satisfies $\dot x =A(t)x$ but the second one not even close. I am understanding something wrong about the "are a basis for the solution of "? I've though also about something like a linear combination of the two solutions but can't find something useful...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a typo. It should be $\varphi_2=(\exp(-t),1)$.

(And you seem to have copied the top left entry in $A$ wrong; it's $1$, not $2$, in my book at least.)